# PostgreSQL get date

Tags: postgresql, date

I have the following query which returns the date as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, but I would like to extract the time and date as separate columns, how can I do this please?  I am new to PostgreSQL

Thanks
Kath

```
select 
    up.mis_id, 
    up.name, 
    up.surname, 
    es.created as "signed in", 
    es1.created as "signed out", 
    bb.name as "location"


from users_person as up

join users_role as ur on ur.id = up.role_id
join events_event as ee on ee.user_id = up.id
join events_swipe as es on es.id = ee.sign_in_id
join events_swipe as es1 on es1.id = ee.sign_out_id
join buildings_building as bb on bb.id = es.location_id
```

Answer (score 1):

use explicit casting, for time:

```
es.created::time
```

and for date:

```
es.created::date
```

Eg:

```
t=# select now()::time(0) "Time",now()::date "Date";
   Time   |    Date
----------+------------
 08:19:59 | 2017-06-06
(1 row)
```

Comment: This has worked to a point, the date and time are now separate (This is great), however the format of the date is still dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss eg 06/06/2017 00:00:00

Comment: this is totally different question - ask it. but please first look for the existing answer - I'm sure it is answered on SO already

Comment: @KathH that's just how your client displays it. PostgreSQL sends a `date` only for `es.created::date` (which does not have any time component in it).

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_char`. See Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html)

```
select to_char(current_timestamp, 'HH12:MI:SS') as time,  
       to_char(current_timestamp, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as date;
       time   |    date    
    ----------+------------
     04:43:13 | 06/06/2017
    (1 row)
```